# Angular Material TabNavBar's Ink-Bar Not Highlighting Route With Children

Tags: angular, angular-material2

**Outline**

My simple Angular SPA is using Angular Material components. My `app.component` template displays a `mat-tab-nav-bar` with a few links to place feature components within the `router-outlet`. One of these components (Reports) is part of a feature Module and the `reports.component` template has its own `mat-tab-nav-bar` forming a sub-menu. Here's an image of the menu:

[image: Example Menu]

All of the routing for the main tabs correctly display their respective components, including the Reports component which displays its own set of Reports tabs. All of the Reports tabs also correctly display their respective components.

My problem, as depicted in my image, is that when Reports is selected in the main menu, the Ink Bar does not animate to be beneath the selected tab, it remains at the last tab selected.

**Code**

Here are the Angular dependencies as defined in my `package.json`:

```json
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "5.2.2",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/material": "5.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
```

My `app.component` template includes the following `mat-tab-nav-bar`:

```html
<nav id="tabNavBar" #tabNavBar mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [routerLink]="link.path"
     routerLinkActive
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
     #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="rla.isActive"
     style="height: 64px;">
       {{ link.label }}
  </a>
</nav>
```

The `app.component` code is as follows:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { INavLink } from "./core/interfaces";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'app';
  versionNumber: string = "";
  navLinks: INavLink[] = [
    { label: 'Home', path: '/home' },
    { label: 'Data Entry', path: '/data-entry' },
    { label: 'Reports', path: '/reports' },
    { label: 'Campaigns', path: '/campaigns' },
    { label: 'Utilities', path: '/utilities' }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {

    // Set the version number.
    this.versionNumber = '0.0.1';

  };
}
```

I have defined the app level routing code in `app-routing.module.ts`:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/components/home.component';
import { DataEntryComponent } from './data-entry/components/data-entry.component';
import { ReportsComponent } from './reports/components/reports.component';
import { CampaignsComponent } from './campaigns/components/campaigns.component';
import { UtilitiesComponent } from './utilities/components/utilities.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'data-entry', component: DataEntryComponent },
  { path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent },
  { path: 'campaigns', component: CampaignsComponent },
  { path: 'utilities', component: UtilitiesComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

If I remove the child navigation, including the `router-outlet`, from my `reports.component` the Ink-Bar does animate as expected beneath the Reports tab.

Here is my `reports.module.ts` code:

```ts
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

/* Angular Material */
import { MaterialModule } from '../core/material.module';

/* Components */
import { ReportsComponent } from './components/reports.component';
import { ReportsDesignChangesComponent } from './components/reports-design-changes.component';
import { ReportsEquipmentComponent } from './components/reports-equipment.component';
import { ReportsStationComponent } from './components/reports-station.component';

export const reportsRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'design-changes', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'design-changes', component: ReportsDesignChangesComponent },
      { path: 'equipment', component: ReportsEquipmentComponent },
      { path: 'station', component: ReportsStationComponent }
    ]
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(reportsRoutes),
    MaterialModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ReportsComponent,
    ReportsDesignChangesComponent,
    ReportsEquipmentComponent,
    ReportsStationComponent
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  entryComponents: [
    ReportsComponent,
    ReportsDesignChangesComponent,
    ReportsEquipmentComponent,
    ReportsStationComponent
  ]
})
export class ReportsModule {
}
```

My `reports.component.html` template includes the following `mat-tab-nav-bar`:

```html
  <nav id="reportsNavBar" mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary" style="background-color: hsla(230, 80%, 50%, 0.2);">
    <a mat-tab-link
       *ngFor="let link of reportNavLinks"
       [routerLink]="link.path"
       routerLinkActive
       [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
       #rla="routerLinkActive"
       [active]="rla.isActive"
       style="height: 64px;">
      {{link.label}}
    </a>
  </nav>
```

The `reports.component.ts` code is very simple:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';
import { INavLink } from "../../core/interfaces";

@Component({
  templateUrl: './reports.component.html',
  styleUrls: ["./reports.component.scss"]
})
export class ReportsComponent {

  reportNavLinks: INavLink[] = [
    { label: 'Design Changes', path: 'design-changes' },
    { label: 'Station', path: 'station' },
    { label: 'Equipment', path: 'equipment' }
    ]
}
```

**Summary**

Probably a very simple error on my behalf which is preventing the Ink-Bar from moving to be beneath the Reports tab, I just can't see it. I would be very grateful if someone can provide some advise to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

After many many hours of looking at this, just after posting the question I work it out!

The `mat-tab-nav-bar` in my `app.component` template specified:

```
[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
```

Of course the URL will not be exactly `http://localhost:5000/reports` because the child routing will add an additional part to the URL such as `http://localhost:5000/reports/equipment`. So, I set the `exact` of `routerLinkActiveOptions` to `false` and everything worked fine.

I hope this helps someone else.